# Exception thrown by code: Stack trace shows this is the last functioncall made: [UIControl(Deprecated)sendAction:toTarget:forEvent]

Tags: iphone, exception, uitextview

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

     NSLog(@"Inside textfieldDidBeginEditing");

     textFieldBeingEdited = textField;

}

//==============================================================================

-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
     textFieldBeingEdited = NULL;

     [sender resignFirstResponder];

     if (moveViewUp) 
     {
          [self scrollTheView:NO];
     }
}

//==============================================================================

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{
     NSLog(@"Inside keyborad will show");

     NSDictionary *info = [notif userInfo];

     NSValue *aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];

     CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

     float bottomPoint = (textFieldBeingEdited.frame.origin.y + textFieldBeingEdited.frame.size.height /*+ 20*/);

     scrollAmount = keyboardSize.height - (self.view.frame.size.height- bottomPoint);


     if(scrollAmount > 0)
     {
          moveViewUp = YES;
          [self scrollTheView:YES];
     }    
     else 
     {
          moveViewUp = NO;
     }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of the view controller

[image]

when I tap on any one of these text fields. An exception is thrown

```
-[__NSCFType textFieldDidBeginEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3c100

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType textFieldDidBeginEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a3c100'

*** Call stack at first throw:

(

 0   CoreFoundation                      0x010275a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185

 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0117b313 objc_exception_throw + 44

 2   CoreFoundation                      0x010290bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

 3   CoreFoundation                      0x00f98966 ___forwarding___ + 966

 4   CoreFoundation                      0x00f98522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50

 5   UIKit                               0x003a1581 -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 67

 6   UIKit                               0x003a3e62 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 525

 7   UIKit                               0x003a9e11 -[UITextField willAttachFieldEditor:] + 404

 8   UIKit                               0x003bbcdf -[UIFieldEditor becomeFieldEditorForView:] + 653

 9   UIKit                               0x003abf98 -[UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 99

 10  UIKit                               0x003e02c3 -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 328

 11  UIKit                               0x005a8961 -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 208

 12  UIKit                               0x005ab5e2 -[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] + 1676

 13  UIKit                               0x005a24f2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 730

 14  UIKit                               0x0059e4fe -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 47

 15  UIKit                               0x005a4afc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 584

 16  UIKit                               0x005a4ce1 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent + 51

 17  UIKit                               0x0033832a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1292

 18  UIKit                               0x00333ca3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 105

 19  UIKit                               0x00316c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447

 20  UIKit                               0x0031bf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576

 21  GraphicsServices                    0x0197f992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550

 22  CoreFoundation                      0x01008944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52

 23  CoreFoundation                      0x00f68cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215

 24  CoreFoundation                      0x00f65f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979

 25  CoreFoundation                      0x00f65840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208

 26  CoreFoundation                      0x00f65761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97

 27  GraphicsServices                    0x0197e1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217

 28  GraphicsServices                    0x0197e289 GSEventRun + 115

 29  UIKit                               0x0031fc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the method signature be:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

i.e. (void) instead of (IBAction)

Comment: p.s. Same for textFieldDoneEditing

Comment: I changed it to void and tried, no that didint fix the exception. Still getting the exception. It seems that the method is deprecated, but it s a system call so how can I change it?

Comment: Do your UITextFields link to any IBActions?

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for your tips, I just cancelled all the links in IB

OK so I changed the IBAction to void but I forgot that I had to cancel the connections in IB. Once I did that no exception is thrown and the keyboard shows. But now the problem is that, nothing happens when I type something in the 1st UITextfield and want to advance to the next by clicking "NEXT" key.

This makes me think that I need to hook up my "textFieldDoneEditing" method in IB to each UITextField. But what is the event that I hook the method to? there are several options, which one is right?

Comment: Not sure what "NEXT" key you are refering to. This is on iPhone, right?  I wouldn't hook your UITextField to any IBActions unless you ware trying to do something really unusual. The textFieldDoneEditing code will be executed automatically without the need for hooking it up. P.S. This is really a second question, right? ;-)

Comment: @Richard: Im really confused now. I cancelled all connections to any methods in IB and left it as is. Now if I touch the UITextfield the app just crashes.

Comment: The "NEXT" button is on the keyboard instead of the return button. Its purpose is to let the user jump to the next textfield. Nothing happens when I click it

Comment: Did you get your delegate set up properly?